# MVC 3, using divs, dynamically add second column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, multiple-columns

Looping through a list of items and displaying an action link for each item.  If there are more than n items I want to place the (n+1)th item at the top of a second column, and so on...with a max of 4 columns.

CSS is not my forte.  I'm barely a beginner with jQuery (so if jQuery is the answer please give me the jQuery 101 answer)

Each ActionLink is in it's own div (I don't know if this is the "best" way to do this or not).
Open to suggestions.

Code snippet from my view:

```
@foreach (int x in Model.ItemList)
{
     <div>@Html.ActionLink(x.ToString(), "DisplayItem", new { param = x })</div>
}
```

This is an MVC 3 project.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Wheeler posted this handy dandy little extention method which allows you to easily define columns in a loop.

In a nutshell, he wraps your object in another ForEach class object which does the math for you.

Simply specify the number of columns you want and at the end of the loop, within scope, you change to see if the NextRow property is true.

It is a couple of years old, however it fills then need you're looking for I believe.

http://www.paulwheeler.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-foreach-loop-sugar